# Convert BackgroundWorker to Task, best practice?

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a class SimpleTask which looks like this:

```
    public class SimpleTask<T>
    {
        private readonly Action<Exception> _errorAction;
        private readonly Func<T> _produce;
        private readonly Action<T> _then;

        public SimpleTask(Func<T> produce, Action<T> then, Action<Exception> errorAction)
        {
            _then = then ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(then));
            _errorAction = errorAction ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(errorAction));
            _produce = produce ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(produce));
        }


        public void Run()
        {
            using (var backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker())
            {
                var item = default(T);
                backgroundWorker.DoWork += (_, e) => item = _produce();
                backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (_, e) =>
                {
                    if (e.Error != null)
                    {
                        _errorAction(e.Error);
                        return;
                    }

                    _then(item);
                };
                backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

I would like to use a Task instead of a BackgroundWorker but I end up with something like this:

```
    public class SimpleTask<T>
    {
        private readonly Action<Exception> _errorAction;
        private readonly Func<T> _produce;
        private readonly Action<T> _then;

        public SimpleTask(Func<T> produce, Action<T> then, Action<Exception> errorAction)
        {
            _then = then ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(then));
            _errorAction = errorAction ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(errorAction));
            _produce = produce ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(produce));
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            try
            {
                var synchronizationContext = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
                Task.Run(_produce,CancellationToken.None).ContinueWith(t =>
                {
                    if (t.IsFaulted)
                    {
                        _errorAction(t.Exception);
                    }
                    else if (t.IsCompleted)
                    {
                        _then(t.Result);
                    }
                }, CancellationToken.None,TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously,synchronizationContext);

                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _errorAction(ex);
            }
        }

    }
```

Which is not the same after all. In my unit tests I have to add:

```
        [SetUp]
        public void TestSetUp()
        {
           SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());
        }
```

I wonder if I should keep using the BackgroundWorker and not pollute my code with task/async structures? What is best practice?

Comment: I accepted the answer from Matthew. Seems I would be fighting with the preferred syntax otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reinventing the wheel, because the new `async` functionality handles most of this for you.

I assume you want to:

- Run in a background task a compute bound method that returns a result
- Handle any exception thrown by that method
- Access the returned value if no exception occurred

Here's an example of how to do this using `await`.

In this example, the compute-bound method is `int computeBoundFunction()`. The code assumes you have a Windows Forms form with a button called `button1` and a multiline TextBox called `textBox1`:

```
async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.AppendText("Starting task\r\n");

    try
    {
        int result = await Task.Run(computeBoundFunction);

        // Instead of your "then" action, just call the code here.
        // In this example, I'm just appending to a multiline text box.
        // This runs on the UI thread.

        textBox1.AppendText("Task returned " + result);
    }

    // Instead of your "errorAction" action, handle exceptions here.
    // Note that this runs on the UI thread, so you can update controls safely at this point.

    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        textBox1.AppendText("Exception: " + exception.Message);
    }
}

int computeBoundFunction()
{
    Thread.Sleep(2000); // Emulate workload.
    return 42;

    // Comment out the return above and uncomment the line below to test the exception handling:
    //throw new InvalidOperationException("Test exception");
}
```

Note that normally you would never use `async void` instead of `async Task`, but this rule is relaxed for event handlers such as `button1_Click()` in this example.

Comment: As stated I am not interested in async/await syntax throughout my code if possible or not in conflict with best practice. The "Run()" method is not using async/await and I want to keep it that way if it is OK?

Comment: @Gryffe You asked what "best practice" is. This is best practice. And to me, this looks much clearer and easier to understand - but I suppose you must have reasons to not want to do it.

Comment: Also the example runs code in the UI - layer. I do not consider that best practice.

Comment: The background task is *not* running in the UI. The only code running in the UI is that code which actually updates the UI (and that's a requirement in Windows).

Comment: If you did want to handle exceptions in the background task itself (rather than doing something in the UI) you would just put the exception handling in the method used for the task. You could of course pass an `Action` in to the task, but generally that's not necessary because the response is usually to display something in the UI, or to just let the exception propagate up to something that knows how to handle it.